# 403 access forbidden error when access custom url or special character at the end of page

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I am creating a website and my client doing audit of website for security purpose. The error is 403 access forbidden error. When i try to use below url then error shows:

```
 http://localhost/cis_s3/welcome.php::
```

I am trying to do by htaccess. But it didn't access the htaccess. How to remove 404 access forbidden error when user try to access "::" at the end of URL. Currently i am using xampp on localhost. Please help us.

Comment: Follow https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989

Answer (score 0):

remove the :: 
 on the browser just type `localhost/cis_s3/welcome.php` in the url

Comment: If user can type :: then we remove that

Comment: I want to hide these information from Acess forbidden page " localhost
12/7/2017 2:47:46 PM
Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.12 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0 "

Comment: this depends on what webserver you are using. Don't worry, these are not personal information, it doesn't harm your security. And also, a normal user doesn't have any motivation to add :: to the url

Comment: But my client want to hide this information from access forbidden page. Can u tell me how to do that. Client audit the website for security purpose. THe person who audit this website send error to me.